# Deploying Haskell yesod docker container on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yesod

I am trying to upload a yesod Docker container on Google App Engine. The source code is [here](https://github.com/meeshkan/github-webhook-router) and the Docker image is [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/meeshkan/yesod-server-test).

I followed the documentation in the [Custom runtime quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart), and when invoking `gcloud app deploy` the app builds fine after increasing the build timeout, but the container either the readiness check when trying to start or shows the following timeout message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Operation [apps/meeshkan-github-webhook-router/operations/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx] timed out. This operation may still be underway.
```

I have tried experimenting with several things, including a manual readiness check, creating an `/_ah/health` endpoint, and increasing the timeout of the readiness check all the way to 1799 seconds, but none of these actions seem to work.

One issue may be the size of the container (it is 3.2gb), and I could try to prune it down, but I'd only do that if someone could confirm that container size is a contributing factor to deployment problems. Other than that, I'm not sure what could be causing this failure. The docker image starts fine on our local machines.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions!

Comment: I cloned the GIT repository you shared, changed the build timeout to 30 min and go the following error message during the deployment: `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error,
 try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.`

Comment: I'm not versed at all in Haskell and cannot provide you further guidance in this aspect, but there is an issue with the way you are implementing the [split health checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#updated_health_checks) within your app since by checking the logs I noticed in the logs that there where quite a few 503 error messages for readiness checks.

Comment: Thanks @DanielOcando! I tried changing the `app_start_timeout_sec` and it did not make a difference in the outcome. I read the documentation you provided, but I'm not sure from reading it how one implements split health checks. It's my understanding from the docs that nothing needs to be implemented and that the checks are automatic. Could you tell me how to get those logs using the CLI? I can dig into the 503s and see if I can fix them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Notice that your application will in fact need to introduce the following two handlers: `/liveness_check` and `/readiness_check` which will need to return a `200` response. And on the `app.yaml` level you'll need to include the relevant [elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#updated_health_checks). I think that you could refer to the [Yesod Book](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/routing-and-handlers) for the specifics of how to implement the handlers on your application (as I explained my Haskell knowledge is limited).

Comment: Finally, notice that health checks using the /_ah/health path are now deprecated and you'll need to follow this section of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/migrating-to-split-health-checks) for the migration on how to implement split health checks.

Comment: You can use a [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging#reading_log_entries) in order to read the logs using [advanced filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries) if you are interested to use the CLI. But I didn't use this, I simply changed the app build timeout to 30 min, deployed the application  and used the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-application-logs#viewing_logs) to view the logs.

Comment: The current google documentation states: "By default, HTTP requests from health checks are not forwarded to your application container. If you want to extend health checks to your application, then specify a path for liveness checks or readiness checks. A customized health check to your application is considered successful if it returns a 200 OK response code." That seems not to be in line with your statement "your application will need to introduce two handlers." It seems like the default is that HTTP traffic is not forwarded. Is this a bug in the docs or in my reading of them? Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading the docs in that split health checks are enabled by default, so therefore liveness and readiness checks are needed for an app to work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215260/discussion-between-mike-and-daniel-ocando).

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be that, because I was building on Windows, images built using Docker Desktop on Windows gave all shell scripts executable permission automatically, whereas Docker on Linux needs shell scripts to be given the executable permission. By adding this line to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/run.sh
```

Everything worked fine!